# pushing to public repository using git bash

Tags: git, github, github-api

I know how to push to github ( to my own) but i want to know how to push or add something to some other repository, for example today one of my friends sent me message that he has made a repository for our project and sent me https://github.com/******/****?fbclid=IwAR0tE2DKtuKKzhtqMV-NvS9_YuSkq-abHu7QY2tcESOuFOu1kGT_PxFJR7Y
and he asked me to put our project to that repository, how is that possible ?
i tried ' git push < url > ' and it says 'not valid: is this a git repository?'

Comment: please refer to https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Comment: He/She most invite you as the repository contributor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clone your friend repository:

`git clone  https://github.com/******/****.git`

2. Make your own branch:

`git checkout -b new_branch_name`

3. Add or edit code
4. Add new new files

`git add -A`

5. Commit files:

`git commit -m "Commit message"

6. Push files:

`git push -u origin new_branch_name`

7. Make pull request in github from new_branch_name to master branch of project

Answer (score 1):

The shared url doesn't look like a link to repository. 
There are two options provided by github. https and ssh.

**https** links looks like `https://github.com/jacob-nelson/react-native-reusable-ui-components.git` which starts with `*https*` ends with *`.git`*

ssh links looks like `git@github.com:jacob-nelson/react-native-reusable-ui-components.git` which starts with `*git@*` ends with *`.git`*

After all, your friend must add you as a team member on the given repository and provide necessary permissions, before you are able to push code to given repository.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can push to a github repository that you don't own. The most common way is to [create a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/). However, you can also push to a repository that you are not the primary owner of if you are added by the owner as a collaborator and given permission. You can change the collaborators by going to the repository and clicking `Settings` at the top and then `Collaborators` on the left.

You can have multiple remotes in your git repo on your local machine. For instance, you can add a remote for your friend's repository like this:

```
git add remote mybuddy https://github.com/mybuddy/someproject
# Note that there is no ?fbclid=IwAR*** etc
```

and list them with

```
git remote -v
```

Then instead of pushing to `origin` you can push to `mybuddy` as well.